# Adding an HTML formatted column in SQL Server Reporting Services 2005

Tags: html, sql, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a table in the database where a "Description" column is of nvarchar(MAX) type in which HTML string is saved.

Now, what I want to do is to have a report view of that table and the "Description" column renders the contents as HTML formatted already. Is there a possibility for this to be done in SQL Server Reporting Services 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the formatting will be handled automatically, have you tried putting the column on a report?

Comment: i have tried it already but it instead shows HTML text. showing the HTML tags than formatting them. so it is not done automatically.

Comment: Ow, you want it to NOT be formatted like html then actually... You DON't want to see the tags, but instead want it to be formatted like you would view the html in a browser? Okay, that was not clear from your question... I don't think that's possible in SSRS... You would have to put a webbrowser control on your report or something... don't think that's possible.